# Linear algebra encrypted message

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have to find the 3x3 transformation matrix that was used to encrypt the message.
The message is

```
EL ALGEBRA LINEAL INTERESANTE SI ES
```

The encrypted message is

ZIÑMZGKCCYIDUSJGJTCMBQXVWFMLIO

Also decipher the following message

DUWQXIBOWJCRPOSLDAWKUJHNIÑY

My try:
I have tried a lot to find the 3x3 transformation matrix using the hill coding assigning a number to each letter of the alphabet

[image]

but I have not been able to advance, the alphabet and the language of the message is Spanish.

Any information or help you can give me to find the 3x3 transformation matrix would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say you've "tried a lot", what does this mean? What have you tried, where did it go wrong, etc.? Since you have both plaintext and ciphertext, you can set up a bunch of linear systems of equations (modulo 27, presumably) to solve for the matrix... have you done this?

Comment: @prets, I have tried to formulate several systems of equations, but none has given me the result I am looking for, I know that it must be modulo 27 due to the alphabet, I think the error is that I do not know how to correctly formulate the systems of equations, since I get quite confused

Comment: Well for example, from the first three letters of the plaintext and ciphertext, we have $$\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 11 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \equiv \begin{pmatrix} 26 \\ 8 \\ 14 \end{pmatrix} \pmod{27}.$$ Multiplying that out you get three equations with nine unknowns. Now continue playing with the next three letters, and the next three letters, and so on (though the first nine are enough).

Comment: (Alternatively you can solve for the inverse matrix directly by swapping the roles of the vectors above, but the procedure is the same.)

Comment: @prets, Thank you very much for your help, I will follow your instructions ;)